# Running multiple sketches on Arduino

Tags: arduino, android-sdcard, bootloader

I'm currently using a custom board that runs on an ATMEGA644P with an attach TFT display. I want to run two separate sketches on it, one of the sketch is complex open-source code that is written in C and the other is my own code that I have coded in Arduino. Combining the two is quite complex and time consuming as they don't run on the same core libraries.

My intention is to have two sketches in hex format uploaded to the board and have a selector switch that will boot into the correct sketch based on the state of the switch. I have research a few solutions but none seem to fit my need exactly, here are the solutions I have researched:

#### Solution 1

Using [AVRmultisketch](https://github.com/JonMackey/AVRMultiSketch) by Jon Mackey.

This uses a custom app that compiles multiple ino files and a selector sketch where the selector sketch will set the starting address of the sketch in the memory. Main problem with this is one of my sketch is not available in ino format.

#### Solution 2

Booting from SD card.

Since I have an SD card attached to the board, I was wondering if I can store both hex files in the SD card and either use a custom sketch or bootloader to select which sketch to use. Unfortunately, I can't find lots of documentation about this. Most methods show how to upload sketches from SD card directly without any selection process.

Are there any guides or methods I can use to achieve my goal?

Comment: IMO an 8bit AVR controller isn't the proper target to invent and run a multitasking operating system. Even an atmega644. BTW: A c++ file should be renameable to .ino, but of course you're responsible for any code you compile.

Comment: On Harvard architecture, you can only run code from the program space (which SD card isn't). You can't modify it at runtime either.

Comment: Your "intention" mentioned above isn't how a 644 works (or any other microcontroller or microprocessor, for that matter).  Code execution starts at the same place every time it boots or resets.  Read the datasheet.  Then you'll realize why your idea cannot work as phrased.

Comment: Is it possible to use https://github.com/zevero/avr_boot this to upload the sketch from the SD card but have a selector program in the bootloader or some sort?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'm not sure if this is the only way or the best way but I manage to do this by using the [avr_boot](https://github.com/zevero/avr_boot) bootloader that will upload a sketch from the SD card on boot. I have successfully tested it with an arduino nano (ATMEGA328P).

Firstly, ensure the default files can be compiled. Then modify the Makefile according to the guide. The boot address can be calculated by multiplying the boot address by 2.For example boot address for ATMEGA328P where the high fuse bit is set to 0xD8 is 0x7000 . Also take note of the CS pin of the SD card.

Then modify the main.c file for line 39

```
const char filename[13] ="FIRMWARE.BIN\0";
```

with this

```
const char filename1[14] ="FIRMWARE1.BIN\0";    // EDIT FILENAME HERE
const char filename2[14] ="FIRMWARE2.BIN\0";
```

You can use any file name you want, just ensure they are all uppercase and take not of the array size.
Then replace this line 194

```
fresult = pf_open(filename);
```

with this

```
DDRB &= ~(1 << PB1);
if ((PINB & (1 << PB1)))   /* test button pressed */
{
    fresult = pf_open(filename1);   
}else{

    fresult = pf_open(filename2);
}
```

I'm using PB1 as a selector pin. Hence, it will open filename1 when its high and filename2 when its low. Now, every time the chip is booted, it will check the state of PB1 and upload the correct sketch from the SD card. This may take some time depending on the size of your sketches. It will also wear out the PROGRAM MEMORY 10000 write cycles which is a lot anyway. A possible fix is to disable the boot reset vector by setting the high fuse bit to 0xD9. This will make it only enter the bootloader when the reset button is pressed instead of when powered on.

I managed to get this working on the ATMEGA644PA too with the proper configuration. However, it only works with the boot reset vector enabled. I'm not sure for the cause of this problem but it will do for now.